# How to file open with different filename using python ftplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

My current python code:

```
import ftplib
import hashlib
import urllib

def ftp():
  hashing="123"
  ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
  ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

  m=hashlib.md5()
  file = open('Desktop/test.png','rb')
  m.update(hashing)
  dd = m.hexdigest()
  ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

  file.close()
  ftp.quit()
```

I got different filename that consist of test.png, test1.png and test2.png. And i wanted to open the file and store it whenever any of the file is being open.
I tried using * asterisk and i got an error:

```
file = open('Desktop/*.png, 'rb')
```

Comment: I'm confused, do you have the files ```test1.png, test2.png, ``` etc already? If so, then glob for them first and make a list of them? Then loop over the list. Maybe I am misunderstanding, your question is not clear.

Comment: Those 3 files are in my desktop.

Comment: do you want the ftp function to find all those files or work on one file per call to the function?

Comment: Yes i wanted to do that

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version instead:

```
import os
import ftplib
import hashlib
import glob

image_directory = '/home/Desktop/images/'

hashing = "123"
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(hashing)
dd = m.hexdigest()

ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

for image in glob.iglob(os.path.join(image_directory, 'test*.png')):
   with open(image, 'rb') as file:
      ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

ftp.close()
ftp.quit()
```

I hope you realize this will just write the same file over and over again on your FTP server, since `dd` is never updated.

You also really shouldn't be using MD5 anymore. If you just want to store the files with the checksums, try this version instead:

```
import os
import ftplib
import hashlib
import glob

def get_sha512(file):
    f = open(file, 'rb')
    value = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).digest()
    f.close()
    return value

image_directory = '/home/Desktop/images/'

ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

for image in glob.iglob(os.path.join(image_directory, 'test*.png')):
   hash = get_sha512(image)[:16]
   with open(image, 'rb') as file:
      ftp.storbinary('STOR {}.png'.format(hash), file)

ftp.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: iglob is more efficient

Comment: When i run the script , and i got this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin403/ftpttest.py", line 17, in <module>
    for image in glob.iglob(os.path.join(image_directory, 'test*.png')):
NameError: name 'glob' is not defined

Comment: Oops sorry about that.

Comment: Now i got this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Use glob to find the files, then loop over the list from glob running ftp() on each file?

```
import ftplib
import hashlib
import urllib
from glob import glob

def ftp(filename):
  hashing="123"
  ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
  ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

  m=hashlib.md5()
  file = open(filename,'rb')
  m.update(hashing)
  dd = m.hexdigest()
  ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

  file.close()
  ftp.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # get the files
   templist = glob('test*.png')

   # loop over the files we found
   for filename in templist:
      ftp(filename)
```

Comment: How to you run the whole program? i got this error: TypeError: ftp() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Copy everything I put into a file and run it with:  python myfile.py in the same directory as the pngs (I've updated the code)

In your error above you are still not passing the filename to ftp() function. The answer is in the error. It now expects 1 argument (the filename) and you gave it 0. The lines below the function are what pass this argument to ftp()

Comment: i try running in this manner:  import ftpttest then print ftp(filename) and i got the error stated that filename is not defined.

Comment: of course filename is not defined, you are not making the templist and looping over it! You cannot pick and choose parts of the solution, it's not a solution then. I have provided you with a complete example code but you refuse to run it and test it properly... good luck.